# Draw over a video in an iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am looking for a method so that i can make an iphone application which plays video and the user be able to draw over the video that is being played..
I would really appreciate it if some one could share some information on this regard..

Answer (score 3):

In the simplest case, you could just put a UIView with a transparent background on top of the video being played.

If you want to merge/flatten the images, it gets a bit more complicated. Can you go into more detail on exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: I would like to know the complexity when tryin to save the drawn image over the video..

Answer (score 0):

Hey there so yes putting a UIVIew over the video is going to be your best bet and then use quartz2d for drawing over it. And then lets say you would like to take a screen shot go ahead and use this code.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

There you are! Oh and if you wanna say put an image or a UIIMageView over the video. Its not different at all. Just add the UIImageView to the UIView thats over the video:) Enjoi!